# classes in Python: AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, class, selenium, inheritance

I`m writing simple scripts for test automation using Selenium WebDriver in Python, but the issue relates to Python, not to Selenium. 
There two classes FindByXPATH_1(base) & FindByXPATH_2(derived). I want to call an attribute "driver" from the base class in a method of FindByXPATH_2, but when I ran the code the AttributeError shows up: "type object 'FindByXPATH_1' has no attribute 'driver'"

Here is the code:

```
class FindByXPATH_1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver_location = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.driver_location)
        self.driver.get('https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice')

from basics.xpath_1 import FindByXPATH_1
import basics #the classes are in two different python files

class FindByXpath_2(FindByXPATH_1):
    def __init__(self):
        FindByXPATH_1.__init__(self)

    def find_by_starts_with(self):
        starting_with = FindByXPATH_1.driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, 
        '//div[@class="view-school"]//h3[starts-with(@)class, "subtitle"]')
        print(len(starting_with))

test = FindByXPATH_2()
test.find_by_starts_with()
```

After running the code I get a message "AttributeError: type object 'FindByXPATH_1' has no attribute 'driver'"
How can I call that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line here:

```
    starting_with = FindByXPATH_1.driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, 
    '//div[@class="view-school"]//h3[starts-with(@)class, "subtitle"]')
```

You should be calling `self.driver.find_elements` otherwise you are trying to access a class variable of `FindByXPATH_1` and not the instance variable `driver`